# Using Html.Action with a controller in a subfolder

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building a webapge using asp.net mvc4. For organization, I would like to put some of the controllers inside a subfolder in the Controllers folder. For example:

```
 Controllers
   AccountController
   BlahController
   Dashboard (Folder)
     ChickenController
     BeefController
```

To use BeefController (which returns a partial view), it seems as though I should use:

```
 @Html.Action("Index", "Dashboard/BeefDashboard")
```

However this gets me the following error:

```
 The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController.
```

How would I be able to use BeefController?

Comment: ASP.Net MVC does not do subfolders.  You should use areas.

Comment: Reading about areas it appears that they are intended for separate areas of a site that have separate concerns, eg, customer support, product catalog, ect.  This for a dashboard that will appear on every page, but it's content repentant on role.  It looks like areas might be my only option though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There no physical sub folder concepts in the ASP.NET MVC world. What you should do is to have an action method in Dashboard controller, which accepts a parameter and then return specific views according to that.

```
public class DashBoardController: Controller
{
  public ActionMethod Index(string id)
  {
    if(id=="chicken") 
    {
      return PartialView("Chicken");
    }
    else if(id=="beef") 
    {
      return PartialView("beef");
    }
    return View("NotFound");
  }

}
```

Now you can access those like

```
Dashboard/beef
Dashboard/chicken
```